# remove a string from the column name

Tags: r

I have a table with column name is:

```
> head(a1)[1:5,1:3]
                a1_a1_AAACCTGAGCGTTTAC-1 a1_a1_AAACCTGAGTCGCCGT-1 a1_a1_AAACCTGGTAGGACAC-1
ENSG00000243485                        0                        0                        0
ENSG00000237613                        0                        0                        0
ENSG00000186092                        0                        0                        0
ENSG00000238009                        0                        0                        0
ENSG00000239945                        0                        0                        0
```

I want to delete the "a1_" in my column name.

Thanks in advance for great help!

Best,

Yue

```
> head(a1)[1:5,1:3]
                a1_AAACCTGAGCGTTTAC-1 a1_AAACCTGAGTCGCCGT-1 a1_AAACCTGGTAGGACAC-1
ENSG00000243485                     0                     0                     0
ENSG00000237613                     0                     0                     0
ENSG00000186092                     0                     0                     0
ENSG00000238009                     0                     0                     0
ENSG00000239945                     0                     0                     0
```

Answer (score 2):

if you want to remove just one a1

```
library(stringr)
colnames(a1) <- str_remove(colnames(a1), "^a1_")
```

base R

```
colnames(a1) <- gsub("^a1_", "",colnames(a1))
```

Comment: Hello NotThatKindODr, Thank you so much for your great help! Both of the ways are work! Really appreciated!  Yue

Comment: Anytime, Happy to help!